# Setting up Cipher for Open SSL

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I want to set the cipher suit as per my requirement each time my system boots up. However, if I consider the case where I accidentally write the wrong Cipher String in `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list()` it will fail to add cipher and end up no https connection to system. To over come this issue I am planning to add some recovery in which case if it fails to set the cipher defined by user it will set-up the connection using default string so my system does not boot up without https connection.If I pass the right string to `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list()` function it works. In theory it seems to work perfect but when it comes to practical it fail very badly.Here is my code,

```
ret = SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list (pMudPort->pMudPortSSLState->pSSLCtx,"Temp");
    printf("Return = %d -------------------\n",ret);
if(!ret)
{
    printf("fail to set cipher -------------------\n");
    printf("setting to default -------------------\n");
    SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list (pMudPort->pMudPortSSLState->pSSLCtx,
                             pSSLConfiguration->pCipherList);
}
```

Here,
"Temp" is just to make sure it fails for the first time.
Even if I am overwriting cipher string second time my system does not support https.
Is it the right way to set the cipher again or I need to clean up something before assigning cipher again?

Comment: Is your second call to `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` returning success?

Comment: Show the string you are using (`pCipherList`). Is this a client, or is this a server?

Comment: @YSU : Yes, my second call returns '1' which is success.

Comment: @jww : pCipherList = " ALL:!aNULL:!MD5@STRENGTH" which works perfect.I have tested it.

Comment: `"ALL:...:FOO:BAR"` will work fine. `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(3)` succeeds if at least one cipher is matched. See the docs at [`SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html). You are pursuing a problem that does not exist.

Comment: @jww : I am facing a problem and that is the reason this post is.I have read the document already and found it should work but it really did not work in practical. Does it set any flag if I pass wrong cipher and it check that flag which creating connection and found cipher was wrong(Even if second time it was right) and fail to connect?